# Add a query string to Entity reference Auto complete CCK Field

Tags: 7, entities

I have a CCK field that is a [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) with auto complete. And in the "Manage Display" `Link label to the referenced entity`.

How can I add a query string to this URL?

Is there any hook avialabe? I had tried using `<themename>_preprocess_field` but no luck.

Current URL is  : example.com/abc
Need Query String : example.com/abc?cid=asdfasdf

This is my array. I didnt find `['entity']` entity in the array. Actually it is an taxonomy reference.

```
[field_article_tags] =&gt; Array
        (
            [und] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [tid] =&gt; 707
                            [taxonomy_term] =&gt; stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [tid] =&gt; 707
                                    [vid] =&gt; 2
                                    [name] =&gt; free prescriptions
                                    [description] =&gt; 
                                    [format] =&gt; plain_text
                                    [weight] =&gt; 0
                                    [uuid] =&gt; d185d2a4-59e5-470d-8692-ea23348d7a63
                                    [vocabulary_machine_name] =&gt; article_tags
                                    [rdf_mapping] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [rdftype] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] =&gt; skos:Concept
                                                )

                                            [name] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; rdfs:label
                                                            [1] =&gt; skos:prefLabel
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [description] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:definition
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [vid] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:inScheme
                                                        )

                                                    [type] =&gt; rel
                                                )

                                            [parent] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:broader
                                                        )

                                                    [type] =&gt; rel
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [tid] =&gt; 2157
                            [taxonomy_term] =&gt; stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [tid] =&gt; 2157
                                    [vid] =&gt; 2
                                    [name] =&gt; prescription charge
                                    [description] =&gt; 
                                    [format] =&gt; 
                                    [weight] =&gt; 0
                                    [uuid] =&gt; 6bf69030-99b9-42e2-83dd-1f63e5a7d1d4
                                    [vocabulary_machine_name] =&gt; article_tags
                                    [rdf_mapping] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [rdftype] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] =&gt; skos:Concept
                                                )

                                            [name] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; rdfs:label
                                                            [1] =&gt; skos:prefLabel
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [description] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:definition
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [vid] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:inScheme
                                                        )

                                                    [type] =&gt; rel
                                                )

                                            [parent] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:broader
                                                        )

                                                    [type] =&gt; rel
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [tid] =&gt; 1515
                            [taxonomy_term] =&gt; stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [tid] =&gt; 1515
                                    [vid] =&gt; 2
                                    [name] =&gt; prescription charges
                                    [description] =&gt; 
                                    [format] =&gt; plain_text
                                    [weight] =&gt; 0
                                    [uuid] =&gt; 9fed77c3-42c3-421b-ba05-d62b18428702
                                    [vocabulary_machine_name] =&gt; article_tags
                                    [rdf_mapping] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [rdftype] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] =&gt; skos:Concept
                                                )

                                            [name] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; rdfs:label
                                                            [1] =&gt; skos:prefLabel
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [description] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:definition
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [vid] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:inScheme
                                                        )

                                                    [type] =&gt; rel
                                                )

                                            [parent] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [predicates] =&gt; Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] =&gt; skos:broader
                                                        )

                                                    [type] =&gt; rel
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: where is this link showing? if on a page -- it could be possible to add this in your content type template... or is it a view?

Comment: Its on Content type template!!

Comment: Did you get it resolved then?

Comment: Nope. I have to hack the module to get this done, though I am not happy to do so...!!!!

Comment: You shouldn't have to hack the module. Did you try my answer and it didn't work? What was the result/error?

Comment: Updated my answer, find the result of my array. I couldnt able to find ['entity'] in that array.

Comment: This array result you added is only for the field_article_tags... did you output and look through the $node object?

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach that might work for you, using the preprocess_page hook (see [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) for more background info).

In your theme's template.php, add this:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   if ($variables['node']->type = 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE') {
     debug ($variables['node'], 'Node:', TRUE);
   }
}
```

Then look through your node object and find your CCK field HTML which contains the link, and drill it down on the debug by adding the array/object children until you get the exact path to the link, my guess is it will be something like $variables['node']->field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME['YOUR_LANGUAGE'][0]['entity']... and the rest will depend on your entity structure.

Now replace the 'debug' line with your link path and append the value to your link, something along this:

```
$variables['node']->field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME->['YOUR_LANGUAGE'][0]['entity']->value = $variables['node']->field_YOUR_FIELD_NAME->['YOUR_LANGUAGE'][0]['entity']->value . YOUR_QUERY_STRING;
```